# line integral definition

Tags: calculus

I am reading "Advanced Calculus" by David Widder. In chapter 7, "Line and Surface Integrals", he defines the following:

$x_{0} = \phi(a), y_{0} = \psi(a), x_{1} = \phi(b), y_{1} = \psi(b)$   and the line integral goes along the curve $\Gamma$.

But then, later on page, (219), he defines a theorem where he assumes that
A) $\Gamma$ is a regular curve.
B) $f(x,y) \in C$ on $\Gamma$ and C)
$\int_\Gamma f(x,y) \,dx$ and $\int_\Gamma f(x,y) \,dy$ exist.

He then states that "by the law of the mean",

$$ \int_\Gamma f(x,y) \, dx = \lim_{\|\triangle\|\to 0}    
\sum_{i=1}^n f(\phi(t_i), \psi(t_i)) \phi^\prime(t_i^{\prime})(t_i - t_{i-1})$$

The norm $\|\triangle\|$ is the smallest subdivision similar to the sub-division with reimann integrals.

I think that know what the law of the mean is but can someone explain how above is obtained.

My understanding is that the law of the mean says that if you have function $F$ that has endpoints and $a$ and $b$ then

$$F(b) - F(a) =   F^{\prime}(\epsilon)(b - a)\text{ for some  } \epsilon \in (a,b).$$

But I don't see how he goes from the law of the mean to that more complex statement. Thanks a lot. Even a reference is fine.

Comment: You might look at mean value theorems (or laws of the mean) for *integrals*, as opposed to derivatives.

Comment: You write "if you have an increasing function that has endpoints and $a$ and $b$ and we denote the function by $F$, then
$F(b) - F(a) =   F^{\prime}(\epsilon)(b - a)\text{ where }\epsilon \in (a,b).$"  That's a lousy way of saying it.  "where" should be used to say what you notation means, not as a quantifier.  You could say "for _some_ $\epsilon\in(a,b)$."  And it does not apply only to increasing functions.  It applies to any function that is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The norm should be the length of the LARGEST interval in the partition, not the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ be paremetrization of the curve then,

$$F(x,y)=F(\alpha(t))$$ on the curve. Now, it only depends $t$ so we can apply "law of mean".

Comment: thanks ted. I'll look up the mean value theorem for integrals. thanks michael. I said it wrong. my bad. thanks mesel but I still don't see how they get that equation.

Comment: ted: I looked up the law for integrals and I understand it. basically it says that the integral of a function equals the averagwe value of the function times the distance covered by the endpoints of the integral. but I still don't see how that translates into what I wrote. thanks for any insights.